# Select particular node and its value from XElement

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml, xelement

I have below xml as XElement .

```
<a:Requirement xmlns:b="ABC.Domain.BM.Contract, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" i:type="b:ABC.Domain.DM.Contract.Base.SR.DR" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ABC.Domain.BM.Contract.Base.SR">
  <Id xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ABC.Common.Contract">123123123123-005d-4fb3-b5f9-21312312312</Id>
  <Name xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ABC.Common.Contract"> Invoice</Name>
  <a:CBy xmlns:c="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ABC.Domain.DM.Contract.Base">
    <c:User xmlns:d="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ABC.Common.Contract">
      <d:Id>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</d:Id>
    </c:User>
  </a:CBy>
  <a:DueIn>
    <a:Span>qwede</a:Span>
    <a:Type>Days</a:Type>
  </a:DueIn>
  <a:MBy xmlns:c="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ABC.Domain.DM.Contract.Base">
    <c:User xmlns:d="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ABC.Common.Contract">
      <d:Id>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</d:Id>

    </c:User>
  </a:MBy>
  <a:Note />
  <a:TaskName> Invoice</a:TaskName>
  <a:ABy xmlns:c="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ABC.Common.Contract">
    <c:Id>123123123123-9766-4ce3-9801-6992042dfdf3</c:Id>

  </a:ABy>
  <a:Doc xmlns:c="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ABC.Common.Contract">
    <c:Id>bb4995d5-a6fe-4c4d-8fd7-123123123123123</c:Id>

  </a:Doc>
</a:Requirement>
```

How Can I select different Id tags to find out its values?
like Id under  Requirement , User , Aby , Doc

I tried `requirement.Descendants().Where(r=>r.Name.LocalName=="Id")`
which returns me All ids present in Xlement , How can I select perticular Id in any of tag?

Answer (score 0):

You've to take namespaces into account. Following gets you all Id nodes

```
    XNamespace ns = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ABC.Common.Contract";
    var result = requirement.Descendants(ns + "Id")
                     .ToList();
```